# Failed to serialize 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity' HazelcastCache

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, serializable

I am using Hazelcast for cache,

My Controller looks like this one:

public ResponseEntity find(String user) {

.....

return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseDto(list, null));

}

When the Hazelcast is trying to save in cache:
 Exception: Failed to serialize 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

ResponseEntity is not serializable

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Rrue, have you managed to find a solution to this? I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was split my code into two methods, one that returns the `ResponseEntity` object, and one that returns the input to the `ResponseEntity` object, which in your case appears to be your `ResponseDto` object. I then adapted that custom class to implement `Serializable`, so that it can be cached by Hazelcast. Then lastly I put the `@Cacheable` annotation above the method that returns that object, instead of the method that returns `ResponseEntity`. In doing so, I no longer received that error.

Answer (score -1):

To answer you question, you have basically 2 options:

- Change the serialization strategy to something that doesn't need to change the class hierarchy (since you cannot) *e.g.* JSON serialization
- Think whether you want to serialize the `ResponseEntity`, or more likely the underlying DTO that you can make `Serializable`

But the thing is, I don't understand how you cache, or from where, or even why. In order to help you in the best way possible, please remember to define the context first, then state the problem you try to solve by caching, and only then can you describe what how you implemented caching and the exception.

For example, in your question, I infer you're using Spring, but I don't know which version, if it's Spring Boot or not, what dependencies you have, etc.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks! sorry, it is my first time asking here. I am using java 11, spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE, I'm using spring cache and hazelcast, i'm just trying to save the response in the cache. But I'm having several problems trying to mix both technologies.

Comment: I assume you want to create a page cache, with a URL as a key and the `ResponseEntity` as the content. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, But it seems like the ResponseEntity.ok (package org.springframework.http;) is not a candidate to be serialized

Comment: Back to my initial answer. Why do you want to cache the `ResponseEntity` and not the DTO itself? Or you can change the default serialization mechanism (cf. https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#serialization)

Comment: Because I can not change anything else, the service or its classes, I must just add the cache but i can not change the response or any line in the classes already used, that's why I can just change the only class used in the controller and its the ResponseEntity class.

Comment: Did you check the documentation I linked to? Changing the serialization mechanism doesn't touch the application.

If you can only change the controller, then cache the `ResultDTO`. If you need more _e.g._ the HTTP code, create a wrapper class that embeds the DTO and the code. I'm sorry, but in the absence of more context, I cannot help you further.